# Writing Password reset using sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am stuck with user reset password. These are the steps that I have accomplished.

1. User selects 'reset password link'.
2. Sails.js generates GUID and saves it to a resetPassTable.
3. Email is sent to the users email.
4. I have changePwdController that has reset action
5. The email that is sent, contains localhost:1337/changePwd/reset/secrethash
6. User clicks on that link and is directed to my action
7. Basically I have access to that hash that is in id, something like:

   var secretHash =  req.param('id')
8. I check that hash against the one in the database, and can make decision as what to do.
9. If the check is passed, meaning there is that hash in DB...
10. ...how do I present a user with two simple textboxes (new pass and repeat pass) and send button?

Comment: What? You solved all the things from 1 to 9 but you are not able to display a textbox and a button? And some more information please! Code? what have you tried?

Comment: ok... User click on the mail and is taken to my action and there I can verify the hash against the one in database (the one I previously created). What now? I can make res.send(something in here?) I am lost :(

Answer (score 2):

You should show the password reset form when the user clicks on the link from the email (this would be just rendering a view normally). You do need to carry the hash to that view though, maybe an URL param?

Then once the user submits the password reset form then do the password reset or rejection if hash does not match one in the database. So you need two different actions. One for showing the view, and another one the form hits upon submission.